# SELECT в Mysql

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Добрый день!

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT players.uname, itemtypes.it_name,count( playerittemtype.itemtype ) AS count
FROM itemtypes, playerittemtype, players
WHERE itemtypes.`it_id` = playerittemtype.`itemtype` 
AND players.`uid` = playerittemtype.`player` 
GROUP BY playerittemtype.`itemtype`
```

при выводе запроса выводится имя пользователя, название предмета и количество предмета. И вот в чем загвоздка: количество предметов выводится то, которое находится в таблице, а мне нужно, чтобы выводило только количество одного предмета, который назначен данному пользователю. Помогите советом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще то этот запрос не может выполняться, потому что синтаксически неверен - нельзя выбрать поля, по которым нет группировки

уточните, какая цель - посчитать сумму playerittemtype.itemtype? тогда в параметрах count() поставьте звездочку

Comment: мне нужно количество предметов каждого пользователя
а не общая сумма предметов

Comment: Так тот запрос, который приведен в вопросе он работает? я что-то не пойму как это возможно

Попробуйте

SELECT players.uname, itemtypes.it_name,count(*) AS count 
FROM itemtypes, playerittemtype, players 
WHERE itemtypes.it_id = playerittemtype.itemtype
AND players.uid = playerittemtype.player
GROUP BY  players.uname, itemtypes.it_name

Comment: Окей спасибо только что сам этот запрос сделал но я всетаки оставил count(`playerittemtype`.`itemtype`) 
просто нужно было GROUP BY  players.uname, itemtypes.it_name написать

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t_players.uname,t_itypes.it_name,COUNT(t_pit.itemtype) AS t_count FROM playerittemtype AS `t_pit` LEFT JOIN players AS `t_players` ON (players.uid=t_pit.player) LEFT JOIN itemtypes AS `t_itypes` ON (itemtypes.it_id=t_pit.itemtype) GROUP BY t_pit.itemtype
```

Попробуйте через join.